# Location Service in Angular Js ng-map

Tags: angularjs-google-maps

Hi I have been using this Plugin and it's really cool than any other Plugin. But now am facing one scenario in which I need to use Google direction service in my app. . So kindly done one please help me on this. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very late respons.

ngMap has a direction directive since 1.7.0

You can find an example here.

https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/tree/master/testapp

https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/testapp/directions.html